# Python 2.7 JSON dump UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dump

I have a file where each line is a json object like so:

```
{"name": "John", ...}

{...}
```

I am trying to create a new file with the same objects, but with certain properties removed from all of them.

When I do this, I get a UnicodeEncodeError. Strangely, If I instead loop over `range(n)` (for some number n) and use `infile.next()`, it works just as I want it to.

Why so? How do I get this to work by iterating over `infile`? I tried using `dumps()` instead of `dump()`, but that just makes a bunch of empty lines in the `outfile`.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    with open('_{}'.format(filename), 'w') as outfile:
        for comment in infile:
            decodedComment = json.loads(comment)
            for prop in propsToRemove:
                # use pop to avoid exception handling
                decodedComment.pop(prop, None)
            json.dump(decodedComment, outfile, ensure_ascii = False)
            outfile.write('\n')
```

Here is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f47d' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You really should copy/paste the entire error message. But even without it, I'd guess that an element of the JSON isn't compatible with your console encoding.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks, I did so. Could you elaborate? Why is the element encoded fine in the other case I described?

Comment: I said the *entire* error message - which line was the error on? Where was it called from? That's all very useful information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the standard `file.write()` function (called by the `json.dump()` function) does not support unicode strings. From the error message, it turns out that your string contains the UTF character `\U0001f47d` (which turns out to code for the character **EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN**, who knew?), and possibly other UTF characters. To handle these characters, either you can encode them into an ASCII encoding (they'll show up in your output file as `\XXXXXX`), or you need to use a file writer that can handle unicode.

To do the first option, replace your writing line with this line:

```
json.dump(unicode(decodedComment), outfile, ensure_ascii = False)
```

The second option is likely more what you want, and an easy option is to use the `codecs` module. Import it, and change your second line to:

```
with codecs.open('_{}'.format(filename), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
```

Then, you'll be able to save the special characters in their original form.

Comment: Thanks! The second option is what I was looking for.